# Getting current IP of windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I am building a windows phone 7.1 app. I need to find out if the phone is connected to any Wifi and if so, what is its current IP in the local network (ie. 192.168.0.100 like this).
I've been trying to find out these information for some time now. Please help.

I've managed to get the local IP on my console app by using the following code

```
public void ScanIP()
{                
    IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            String localIP = ip.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(localIP);                        
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

However, I need similar thing done for windows mobile 7 app. Any idea ? Please share.

Comment: FYI, the IP can switch *very* frequently e.g. if the user is driving down the freeway.  It can also flip-flop pretty quickly if the user is at the edge of their WiFi range, which happens to me for example in my back yard.

Answer (score 2):

Do a multicast and listen for replies. Once you identify your multicast message, you can get the IP of the sender (which is yourself). You can use [UdpAnySourceMulticastClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpanysourcemulticastclient%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to do the multicasting. In case you're not in a wifi network, you will get a socket failure in the EndJoinGroup call. You should handle the exception and pass a specific value indicating you're not in a wifi network.

More info in this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2011/08/11/finding-your-own-ip-address-on-windows-phone-mango.aspx) by Andy Pennell.

Answer (score 0):

it will provide you the ip address of the phone ...

```
  public static IPAddress Find()
    {
        List<string> ipAddresses = new List<string>();

        var hostnames = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
        foreach (var hn in hostnames)
        {
            if (hn.IPInformation != null)
            {
                string ipAddress = hn.DisplayName;
                ipAddresses.Add(ipAddress);
            }
        }

        IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddresses[0]);
        return address;
    }
```

Comment: This compiles for WP8 but not for WP7